# Is there example .arxml files available which implement concept define in Autosar specification

Tags: autosar

I want to create arxml file.For this I am reading some Autosar specification given on there website.If there is any example .arxml file available which implement what is explain in document will help me understand a concept.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had never seen any ".arxml" file provided (as a example) whith Autosar documentetion specification on the www.autosar.org.

Keep on mind that there is three type of .arxml file for AUTOSAR (for the Vector software stack) - *bswmd, *ecuc and *swc file.

Here is a simple example of MyECU.ecuc.arxml file. Hope this will help you in some way:

[MyECU.ecuc.arxml](https://github.com/nikidimitrow/Learning-AUTOSAR-fundamental/blob/master/BasicsOfAUTOSAR/MyECU.ecuc.arxml)

Comment: Thank you NiKi.Could you please tell me where I can find *sws files?.

Comment: Never search trought Internet for the .swc file for AUTOSAR. Just upload the file ecuM.swc.arxml file into my github profile, so you have .ecuc and .swc of the same module.              
                                                      
https://github.com/nikidimitrow/Learning-AUTOSAR-fundamental/blob/master/BasicsOfAUTOSAR/EcuM_swc.arxml[/link]

Comment: Try it: https://github.com/nikidimitrow/Learning-AUTOSAR-fundamental/blob/master/BasicsOfAUTOSAR/EcuM_swc.arxml

Comment: Thanks a lot NiKi

Comment: Try it: https://github.com/nikidimitrow/Learning-AUTOSAR-fundamental/blob/master/BasicsOfAUTOSAR/EcuM_swc.arxml